# Fullscreen Holo Dialogs

Tags: android, dialog

I have run into a severe problem with an alert dialog in Android. I've extended DialogFragment and I want the dialog to be fullscreen. After a lot of failed attempts I figured out I could get a fullscreen dialog by setting the dialog theme. I've done it like this

`ContextThemeWrapper context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);`

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

since I read this was compatible with older APIs. But sadly, it only works with certain themes, it never works with a holo theme. E.g. if I use Theme_Black_NoActionBar_Fullscreen it will be fullscreen, but if I use Theme_Holo_NoActionBar_Fullscreen, or even Theme_DeviceDefault_NoActionBar_Fullscreen it won't be fullscreen. Whenever Holo is involved the dialog does not fill the screen.

I've even tried defining my own style, extending Theme.Holo with the following settings:

```
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>

    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

But even explicitly setting fullscreen and a null frame and background, etc, does not help, the dialog still refuses to fill the width of the screen (I am testing it on my phone, in landscape mode).

I'd love some help on this, I've been trying to get it to work all day. First I tried setting window attributes using LayoutParams but this doesn't seem to work with a DialogFragment. Thanks.

Comment: Fullscreen dialogs are called Activities :) Why would you wan't that?

Comment: OK, not completely fullscreen, I still want a margin around the dialog window. This is what you get with Theme_Black_NoActionBar_Fullscreen. You get a window that uses most of the width of the screen, with a margin. But with the Holo themes, I just get a window which is half the width of the screen. The dialog contains text so it would be nicer if it used more width. In any case, nothing I've tried allows me to alter the width of the dialog in any way. Surely I should be able to affect the width somehow, rather than having to have the width chosen for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AlertDialogs` are not meant to be made fullscreen. In order to achieve that, you should just use the standard `Dialog` that comes with the `DialogFragment`.  You'll need to add your own layout in order to add buttons to simulate the `AlertDialog`.  More work...yes, but all those android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_* themes will work properly then.

Comment: Thanks very much, it works now. But there is still a slight issue, it won't fill the screen without setting android:minWidth="1000dp" on the linearlayout used with the dialog. But at least it works, thanks.